# Página de download única para cada usuário

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estou tentando criar uma área de usuários em meu site com PHP e MySQL, até agora consegui fazer o sistema de login e uma página privada para os clientes.

A questão é como eu poderia disponibilizar uma página única para cada cliente?

O meu objetivo é fornecer links de downloads exclusivos para cada usuário de forma com que outro usuário não consiga acessar, irei faze-lo a partir do Google Drive, porém não sei como mostrar os links exclusivamente para cada cliente (até tentei inserir os links no banco de dados e mostra-los com echo porém isso me impediria de customiza-los com CSS e HTML depois).

Segue o código que quero implementar:

```
<?php
    include_once ("setting.php");
    @session_start ();

    $nome =  $_SESSION ['nome'];
    $usuario = $_SESSION ['usuario'];

    if (!isset($_SESSION['nome']) && !isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
        header('location: login.php');
        exit;

    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu acho que devias usar banco de dados e não iria te impedir de nada (**na minha visão do problema**)

Para que isso aconteça so tens de fazer uma simples relação de 1 para muitos (porque 1 utilizador pode ter vários links de download (pela lógica))

Imagina a seguinte tabela de **utilizadores**:

```
+----+-----------------+------------------------------------------+
| id |      email      |                 password                 |
+----+-----------------+------------------------------------------+
|  1 | joao@gmail.com  | D6540780F1D484ABF4CF3EE484575822B28EF5FQ |
|  2 | jose@gmail.com  | 88D2C2801C73885F0D0F54374CD51F3288C34F82 |
|  3 | maria@email.com | C97C961736D050F24B1FCE96791546790A2BB668 |
+----+-----------------+------------------------------------------+
```

**OBS** Cada utilizador tem um id unico.

Agora imagina a seguinte tabela **utilizador_links**:

```
+----+---------+-------------------+
| id | id_user |       links       |
+----+---------+-------------------+
|  1 |       1 | google.com        |
|  2 |       1 | stackoverflow.com |
|  3 |       2 | facebook.com      |
+----+---------+-------------------+
```

Nesta tabela podes observar que contem a chave estrangeira **id_user** que se refere ao **ID** do utilizador da 1 tabela de exemplo.

e Para obteres todos os links que o utilizador contem basta fazeres a seguinte consulta como exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM utilizador_links WHERE id_user = $_SESSION['id_user_logado']
```

Neste caso ira retornar todos os links que o utilizador logado possui.

**Isto foi apenas um exemplo como o teu sistema pode tar organizado utilizando base de dados, simples e pratico.**

Se fosses pela tentativa de criar uma pasta para cada utilizador acho que ia dar errado, como irias ter garantia que certa pasta pode ser acessada por certo utilizador ?

Comment: Acho que era realmente isto que estava procurando, irei testar aqui, obrigado pela sugestão!